# hibernate. doesn't link in many to many association

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I have Candidate and Vacancy entities(many to many annotation).

In Candidate mapping:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "candidates", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlTransient
    public Set<Vacancy> getVacancies() {
        return vacancies;
    }
```

In Vacancy mapping:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "vacancy_candidate", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vacancy_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id"))
    public Set<Candidate> getCandidates() {
        return candidates;
    }
```

invocation code:

```
@RequestMapping("/saveCandidate")
    public String saveCandidate(Model model,HttpServletRequest request,HttpResponse response
            ,@ModelAttribute("candidateFromRequest") Candidate candidateFromRequest
            ,@ModelAttribute("skillsIdList") Set<Skill> skills
           ,@ModelAttribute("vacanciesForCandidate") Set<Vacancy> vacanciesForCandidate
           ,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes
            )
    {
        candidateFromRequest.setSkills(skills);
        candidateFromRequest.setVacancies(vacanciesForCandidate);//In debug I saw that here exist vacancy
        for(Vacancy vacancy:vacanciesForCandidate){
            vacancy.getCandidates().add(candidateFromRequest);
        }
        candidateService.update(candidateFromRequest);//invoke  session.update();
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message", "Submitted Correctly");
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("id",candidateFromRequest.getId());
        return "redirect:loadCandidateById";
    }
```

But really there are in database is missed note after this transaction. why?

Comment: Could you paste SQL info for this operation? Anything happens?

Comment: updates only Candidate table

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save in this way you have to change your mapping. Now, `Vacancy` is owning side and `Candidate` is owned.

In your case, you are using `CascadeType.ALL` so it should works.